# When to release objects in a Tab bar application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, tabbar

This is an extension to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786862/xcode-4-tab-bar-application-problem-in-executing-third-tab)

Here is the scenario:

I have three tabs in which a switch is there. When I touch the switch, a label gets updated (ON or OFF) and image of a bulb changes from one jpg to another. So I am using UIImageView in which I am changing the UIImage.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    UISwitch *switch1;
    UILabel *status1;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *switch1;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *status1;
- (IBAction) switch1Change;
@end
```

and the implementation is

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize switch1;
@synthesize status1;
- (IBAction) switch1Change
{
    if (switch1.on) {
        status1.text = @"ON";
        ...
    }
    else {
        status1.text = @"OFF";
        ...
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand when to release the objects. I tried giving the [switch1 release] in - (void) dealloc {} method. But when I switch tabs, the app crashes. How to do this?

Comment: I suspect your crash has nothing to do with the `[switch1 release]` you placed in `[class dealloc]`, because it only gets called when there's a memory warning. I'd suggest looking more closely at the run log and working in debugging mode to see what the actual error that causes the crash is.

Comment: Releasing retained/copied objects (as in your IBOutlets) in your dealloc method (or in ViewDidUnload) is proper. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965399/memory-management-in-objective-c and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html for more details. Did you remove the release statement and it doesn't crash? I'm inclined to think smth else crashes your app...

Comment: @tsakoyan : Yea, I removed the release statements and the app didn't crash. I will look into the run log and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

`[switch1 release]` in dealloc seems correct, what is the crash you get?  It could be unrelated to this.

If you set a breakpoint you'll probably find the tabs do not get deallocated; once loaded by the tab bar it keeps them around.  Also the view controllers for all tabs are loaded at start.